# Run aws cli commands on EMR using Lambda

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, copy, amazon-emr

I have a Lambda function that connects to EMR using boto3. I want to run "aws s3 cp" command on EMR using my lambda function to copy files from S3 to EMR's local directory.

Is there a way to run aws cli commands on EMR using Lambda?

Comment: Pasted the solution to copy from S3 to EMR in this post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56623774/copy-files-from-s3-to-emr-local-using-lambda/56761459#56761459

Answer (score 0):

No.

Amazon Lambda runs from the Internet. It does not have access to run commands on the EMR cluster instances.

You could, theoretically, install the [Systems Manager Agent](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/sysman-manual-agent-install.html) on EMR. (I haven't tried, it, but it should work.) Your AWS Lambda function can then call the Systems Manager [`send_command()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ssm.html#SSM.Client.send_command) function to execute some code on the instance.

See: [AWS Systems Manager Run Command - AWS Systems Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/execute-remote-commands.html)